# VS code Exception error on python language

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[Exception error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjD1l.jpg)

I have suddenly encountered this problem with VS code using python. I have tried reinstalling anaconda and also VS-code itself but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: do you get the same problem when you disable all extensions in vscode? and what about running the code without debug mode?

Comment: I haven't tried compiling with disabling all the extensions. some how I get the feeling that it cannot connect to the debugger at all.

Comment: There was a vscode issue recently mentioning that this might be extension related, so I would give that a go first. See here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/60436

Comment: You can start code without extensions using a flag: `code --disable-extensions`

Comment: Thank you. I will try this and see what happens.